# Is there a word or an expression that describes the bad mood caused by bad weather?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

"Gloomy" comes to my mind naturally for God knows what reason. I'm not sure it's appropriate or not. Maybe some even better words or expressions?

Comment: Seasonal affective disorder?

Comment: Related but not an answer as such *"cabin fever"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Gloomy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gloomy)** is a good thought here, as evidenced by the fact that it is often applied to the weather (i.e. *[gloomy weather](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS446US447&aq=f&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=gloomy%20weather)*) as well as the mood caused by such weather.  There's a good reason for naturally thinking of *gloomy*; it is common in this context.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. I've noticed what I didn't put right.

Answer (score 0):

No better word than gloomy comes to (my) mind. It just may be you answered your own question already!

"Gloomy weather" is a ubiquitous expression so it's no surprise that it entered your mind so readily.

It is also quite appropriate when you consider its definitions, which Oxford Dictionaries Online gives as:

1. Dark or poorly lit, especially so as to appear depressing or frightening; and
2. Causing or feeling depression or despondency.

The first definition is perfect for dark, depressing weather, i.e. gloomy weather, which in turn causes people to feel depressed, i.e. gloomy
!

Comment: I thought of the word probably because of the famous(infamous) song called Gloomy Sunday, which has caused people to commit suicide.